# Publish generated key to Launchpad

Tags: launchpad, keys, pgp

I created a new local PGP key but I dont find how to publish it so Launchpad will recognize it.

All explanations are only in english but in my german Ubuntu I cannot find the tools under those names:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-spacetrace/+editpgpkeys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the following steps are described in [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html) page of the Ubuntu Packaging Guide.

You first need to send your PGP key to the Ubuntu keyserver. To do this, first run `gpg --list-keys` to find out your key ID. The key ID will be the part after `2048R/` or `4096R/`. Next, run `gpg --send-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com keyid`; replace `keyid` with your key ID.

For the second part, run `gpg --fingerprint` to get the fingerprint of your key. This part is in 8 blocks of 4 characters. Copy that, and paste that in the text box in the page in the Edit PGP Keys link.

After submitting, you should see that a key was added, and you should get an email saying that a PGP key was added.

Note that you also need to create an SSH key. You can run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to create a 2048-bit SSH key. It is recommended that you have a passphrase for this key, as this key can not only be used for communication between your computer and Launchpad, but could also be used (by you) to access your computer remotely. Run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, and copy the output. Then, paste this into the section on adding an SSH key.

Comment: I tried, but the new key is not in `gpg --list-keys`. It only exists as a file: `~/.ssh/id_rsa_launchpad` and  `~/.ssh/id_rsa_launchpad.pub`

Comment: Those are SSH keys, and are different from PGP/GPG keys. You still need to tell Launchpad your public SSH key.

Comment: Run `gpg --gen-key`, and follow the prompts. Use RSA and RSA (this means have a separate public key used for verification and encrypting messages (by other people) and a private key that only you have that you use to sign messages).

Comment: I already have some PGP keys in the list, but should I use the same PGP key as for my email? Or generate a new one for just launchpad?

Comment: You can use the same one. I personally do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15623/discussion-between-saiarcot895-and-rubo77).

Answer (score 1):

Another way, use `seahorse` GUI to create/manage/sync your keys (Installed by default in Ubuntu).

**For PGP key:** It will be used mainly to sign packages (PPA's)

1. Open Seahorse (or "Passwords & Keys" in Dash)
2. Select the key (If not yet have one, File → New, follow dialog to the end)
3. From menu: Remote → Sync & Publish Keys...
4. Click on Key Servers → Choose Publish keys to: `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371`, Close
5. Click Sync
6. Right click on key, Properties → Details tab: Copy Fingerprint
7. Submit it to Launchpad

**For SSH key:** It will be used for `bzr` repositories (Code repo)

1. File → Export
2. Copy content of that exported .pub key file and paste it to Launchpad

**Backup your Complete Key OS reinstall:** If you don't want to loose/replace them.

Right click on key → Details → Export SSH:"Complete Key"/PGP:"Private Key"