# Build a Ubuntu debian package

Tags: package-management, ppa, deb, launchpad

I would like to create an Ubuntu package from a single [bash script](https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/blob/master/usr/bin/mouse-speed) I wrote.

Is there a **simple instruction** how to build an Ubuntu package, that can be uploaded to launchpad? (I already [created the PPA and uploaded my PGP- and SSH-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493353/publish-generated-key-to-launchpad/493389#493389)).

I already [created successfully a debian package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141399/20661) (with `Packages.gz` and a PPA hosted at github itself) but that package is missing the needed files that are required in this Ubuntu manual: [Uploading a package to a PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading):

- `.dsc`
- `.changes`
- `.diff.gz` or `.debian.tar.gz`
- and optionally the `.orig.tar.gz` (if you used `debuild -S -sa` to build your package)

How do those files have to look like and how do I create them? (examples, commandline tools?)

Comment: I don't know about simple, but I followed the links from your post to this article about building a package for Ubuntu : http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/

Comment: The first paragraph there on [2. Getting Set Up](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html) already describes that you have to install `pbuilder` which installs some GB on your system, is this really needed for my case? (only one bash script is tested and that works well)

Comment: I'm gonna guess since `pbuilder` is the "package builder", that you will be better off if you do install it.  Perhaps a package could be built by hand by someone with sufficient knowledge.

Comment: You do not need pbuilder to make a .deb from a bash script, but it automates the process and interfaces with launchpad (your ppa). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries and http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/ . There is no real replacement for reading the packaging guidelines if you wish to package a .deb "properly", meaning minimize problems for people who want to use your .deb . Also, without proper packaging, your .deb will never be accepted into the official repos.

Comment: Those files are created by running `debuild -S -sa` or `debuild -S -sd`. `pbuilder` is when you want to test building the package in a clean chroot (where only the minimal Ubuntu packages are present. This is to test that you have covered all necessary dependencies.

Comment: If I use `debuild -S -sa` I get this error: `cannot find readable debian/changelog anywhere!`

Comment: There a few files deemed essential while building a Debian package: `debian/{changelog,compat,control,copyright,rules}` and a few others. Most packaging tutorials talk about them. You can use the command `dh_make -s -n` will generate a set of sample files needed, which you can customize accordingly.

Comment: @rubo77: Note that you also need to be inside and at the top level of the source code tree; the `debian` folder must be a subfolder of your current directory.